# Configure Transaction attempts in Spring JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jta

I have a Spring application with JPA configuration and I want to configure Deadlock retries. How I can configure this in `application.properties` file? Currently I have only this configuration:

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:/global/test
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the *Appendix A - Common application.properties* section of the [official Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html), you can configure:

```
spring.jta.atomikos.properties.recovery.max = n 
#                                             ^-- retry count here, n >= 0, default = 5.
```

given that you are using [Atomikos](https://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/SpringIntegration) as [JTA provider](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-jta.html) in your application at runtime. With Atomikos configured, you can  retry - at least - failed transactions:

> *Number of retry attempts to commit the transaction before throwing an exception.*

This, however, does not guarantee that deadlock situations will be resolved before *1* or *n* retry attempts have been conducted.

You might also want to check the property

```
spring.jta.atomikos.properties.recovery.retry-interval=10000ms
```

which configures the "delay between retry attempts".

Hope this helps.

Comment: I use JpaTransactionManager. Is there any solution for it?

Comment: None that I'm aware of. You can scan/check the "Appendix A - Common application.properties section" for properties that might help; I did not find any other properties of relevance.